# ListBox Update Handling

Tags: c#, optimization, linq, asp.net-mvc

I have `UserGroups` for `Users` to be assigned to in a ListBox in HTML form. Items from listbox can be multi-selected or completely unselected.

In summary currently, I am getting a `int[]` of `GroupId` from client into my action and I am pulling existing assigned usergroups for the user into the action as well. Then I am *comparing the `Length` of both `int[]` to determine whether UserGroups for the User was added or removed* which is depicted in the following flow chart:

[image: flow_chart]

Actual code:

```
var existUserGroups = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID).Single().UserGroups;
var existUserGroupsIds = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID).Single().UserGroups.Select(ug => ug.ID).ToArray<int>();
var newUserGroupsIds = user.GroupId ?? new int[0];

//No change made
if (!existUserGroupsIds.SequenceEqual(newUserGroupsIds))
{
    //Add
    if (newUserGroupsIds.Length > existUserGroupsIds.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newUserGroupsIds.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!existUserGroupsIds.Any(id => id == newUserGroupsIds[i]))
            {
                int id = newUserGroupsIds[i];
                existUserGroups.Add(db.UserGroups.Where(ug => ug.ID == id).Single());
            }
        }
    }
    //Remove
    else if (newUserGroupsIds.Length < existUserGroupsIds.Length)
    {
        var diff = existUserGroupsIds.Except(newUserGroupsIds);
        if (diff != null && diff.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < diff.Count(); i++)
            {
                int id = diff.ElementAt(i);
                existUserGroups.Remove(db.UserGroups.Where(ug => ug.ID == id).Single());
            }
        }
    }
    //Update
    else
    {
        existUserGroups.Remove(existUserGroups.ElementAt(0));
        int id = newUserGroupsIds[0];
        existUserGroups.Add(db.UserGroups.Where(ug => ug.ID == id).Single());
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is working but the code seems to be very tangled. So, please suggest how I can improve this code or how devs usually handle such situations.

Comment: Just want to check I'm guessing correctly: you're using an ORM like Entity Framework, Users and Groups are each entities with their own table, and because they're in a many-to-many relationship you also have a UserGroups table to map them. Is that correct?

Comment: @BenAaronson You guessed correct! But EF handles the join table stuff so all I have for typed models are `User` and `Group`.

Comment: So `db.UserGroup` is what you're calling a `Group`?

Comment: @BenAaronson Yeah, yeah. Sorry for the confusion. Technically, typed models are `UserGroup` and `User`. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Small Code duplication**

```
var existUserGroups = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID).Single().UserGroups;
var existUserGroupsIds = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID).Single().UserGroups.Select(ug => ug.ID).ToArray<int>();
```

can be reduced to

```
var existUserGroups = db.Users.Where(u => u.ID == user.ID).Single().UserGroups;
var existUserGroupsIds = existUserGroups.Select(ug => ug.ID).ToArray<int>();
```

**The `//Add` part**

Should be simplified using a foreach loop and made more readable by using the [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
foreach (int newId in newUserGroupsIds)
{
    if (!existUserGroupsIds.Contains(newId))
    {
        existUserGroups.Add(db.UserGroups.Where(ug => ug.ID == newId).Single());
    }
}
```

**The `//Remove` part**

```
var diff = existUserGroupsIds.Except(newUserGroupsIds);
```

`diff` will never be null => the null check can be skipped
using a for..each instead of a for loop => the check for `diff.Count() > 0` can be skipped

```
var diff = existUserGroupsIds.Except(newUserGroupsIds);
foreach (int id in diff)
{
    existUserGroups.Remove(db.UserGroups.Where(ug => ug.ID == id).Single());
}
```